# PC stops sending video in ubuntu desktop installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

when i try to install ubuntu or simply when i pass to much time on the installation menu, the pc stops sending video and doesn't really do anything, i even had started installation and it had an estimated time remaining of 7 minutes when video went out it never finished installing.

I'm installing from a bootable usb flash drive with ubuntu 16.04.03 amd 64.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening and how to solve it?

English is not my native language, sorry.

Edit: Tried selecting never in the lock option (that i had to do by "Try Ubuntu" i didn't change anything, it still shuts off, if i select the install updates and third party software it doesn't even get to the part where they ask how you want to install, and if i skip that part when i click install it just freezes not doing anything (but the mouse icon shows the loading animation) and then shuts off.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you can resolve this issue simply by changing the Brightness and lock setting as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly it didn't work, it still shuts off, if i select the install updates and third party software it doesn't even get to the part where they ask how you want to install, and if i skip that part when i click install it just freezes doing anything (but the mouse icon shows the loading animation) and then shuts off.